# Make 2 images stay at a fixed place on my background when I reduce browser window size

Tags: html, coding-style

How do I make my image stay at the same spot even when I make my browser window smaller?

Below is my current HTML:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <style>
         body {
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         background-image: url('TPHRG floorplan.png');
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-attachment: fixed;
         background-size:  contain;
         }
      </style>
   <body>
      <img id="ZY" style="position:absolute; top:535px; left:770px; border-radius: 50%; width:50px; height:50px" src="zhi yi face.PNG">
      <img id="Nehemiah" style="position:absolute; top:435px; left:570px; border-radius: 50%;  width:50px; height:60px" src="nehemiah face.PNG">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Title of your question seems little vague.Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: If you want an image with fixed position... try using `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` ...

Comment: Hi thank, for the imformation.